# Maven snapshot artifact publication file name

Tags: maven, maven-3

Have a problem with Maven. For some unfortunate reason I need to figure out the exact name of the snapshot artifact it uploads to Nexus.

For example, my current version is "1.0-SNAPSHOT" and when artifact is uploaded to the repo, it's name is something like "Foo-1.0-20160322.150103-15.jar", SNAPSHOT is replaced with timestamp.

If there any build property (which I couldn't find) or other nice way to extract artifact's name? For this example it should have value "Foo-1.0-20160322.150103-15.jar".

I'm using maven 3.2.5.

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using TeamCity to build and need that name to pass it to the script on one of build steps. Unfortunately that script require _exact_ file name - it then passed later on to another system, etc, it's long story :)

Comment: No *nice way* from Maven cause usually this is not interesting...but could you parse the log output in TeamCity?

Comment: @khmarbaise was trying to avoid it, but it looks like it is the only option :( I wish I use Gradle, it is much more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by default, whenever nexus reads SNAPSHOT it replaces it with timeStamp and a sequenceNumber.
This is a default behavior by nexus whenever it detects a snapshot.
What you can do is to name the artifact projectName-1.0.0-alpha, and then this should work properly.